# How to use the bundle adjustment to optimize homography matrix

Tags: image-stitching

I did mulitiple cameras image stiching project rencently,I estimated the parameters of the cameras first(use autostitch),and calculated the homography matrixs through those parameters,but something wrong and the result is as follows.
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9bap.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AEjb.jpg)

There are more stretchings and more match errors on the left and right sides of the result.Someone told me that I should use bundle adjustment to optimize the homography matrixs,but I don't know what to do,please enlighten me,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The focal lengths of all images (except the left most) are not multiplied by a scaling factor.

Have a look at line 653 of [this](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stitching_detailed.cpp) code.

```
    cameras[i].K().convertTo(K, CV_32F);
    float swa = (float)seam_work_aspect;
    K(0,0) *= swa; K(0,2) *= swa;
    K(1,1) *= swa; K(1,2) *= swa;
```

here K(0,0) and K(1,1) are focal lengths which must be scaled by a scaling factor i.e. swa.